# Clicking the Firebase dynamic link does not call the application (_: continue: restorationHandler :) method in AppDelegate

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-dynamic-links

Using Firebase Dynamic Links, I want to be able to click a link to open an iOS app.

The app is under development and is not yet on the AppStore.

I set it while looking at the document, but even if the app is started by clicking the link, the application (_: continue: restorationHandler :) method in AppDelegate is not called.

I set it according to the following procedure. Is something wrong?

1. Add "pod 'Firebase / DynamicLinks'" to Podfile and install
2. Open the .xcworkspace file
3. Create Dynamic Links “https://XXXX.page.link/test”
4. Access “https://XXXX.page.link/apple-app-site-association”

   > {"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"XXXXXXX.[Bundle
   >   ID]","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}
5. Create a URL type to use for dynamic links
   [image]
6. Enable "Associated Domains" and add "applinks: XXXX.page.link"
   [image]
7. Implement AppDelegate as below

   ```
   import UIKit
   import Firebase
   import FirebaseDynamicLinks

   @UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

       func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
           // Override point for customization after application launch.
           FirebaseApp.configure()
           return true
       }

       // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

       func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
           // Called when a new scene session is being created.
           // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
           return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
       }

       func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
           // Called when the user discards a scene session.
           // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
           // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
       }

       func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                    restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
         let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(userActivity.webpageURL!) { (dynamiclink, error) in
           // ...
         }

         return handled
       }

       @available(iOS 9.0, *)
       func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
         return application(app, open: url,
                        sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                        annotation: "")
       }

       func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
         if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
           // Handle the deep link. For example, show the deep-linked content or
           // apply a promotional offer to the user's account.
           // ...
           return true
         }
         return false
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was calling the scene method of SceneDelegate.

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).

        // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
        let rootView = ContentView()

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }

        guard let userActivity = connectionOptions.userActivities.first(where: { $0.webpageURL != nil }) else { return }
        print("url: \(userActivity.webpageURL!)")
    }

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        print("url: \(userActivity.webpageURL!)") 
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implementation should be in SceneDelgate instead of AppDelegate